# Rubygems cannot use proxy, but proxy does NOT require authentication

Tags: ruby, networking, proxy, rubygems

I have found other questions related to getting Rubygems working behind a proxy, and in all those cases the proxies in question have required a password.  The proxy at work that I am using does NOT require a password, I know this - I use it all the time from my browser and the command line.

I have tried all the following:

I have my http_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, https_proxy and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables all set.

I have passed in the proxy to the 'gem' command manually.

I have tried to download a file from https://rubygems.org/ , and they work perfectly fine accessing an HTTPS url through the proxies, so I am fairly certain the proxy is not the problem.

Here is what I get when I do:

```
$ gem list --remote --source https://rubygems.org/ wasabi

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException)
    407 "Proxy Authentication Required"
```

But the confusing thing is that I KNOW the proxy does not need a username/password!

Just for kicks, I've done an strace on 2 commands: the above 'gem list' command, and a 'curl' command to just download a page over HTTPS from rubygems.org.  Here is what I get:

https://gist.github.com/2929757

Note that 'curl' sends in a command that looks something like:

```
CONNECT rubygems.org:443 HTTP/1.1
Host:  rubygems.org:443
...
...
```

Anyway, it's a long shot, but was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ??